# Installing gtk3 and gtkmm on mac

Tags: macos, gtk3, gtkmm

I have been trying to install gtk+3 and gtkmm on my Macbook for GUI development. I have tried using homebrew and mac install script on gnome website([here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Integration)). I'm not sure what else to do other than download all of the source code and compiling that. I just need some help because most of the tutorials that I found are a little outdated.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For gtk+ 3.x

`brew install gtk+3`

for gtkmm 3.x

`brew install gtkmm3`